# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS : fingerprint reader not working

Tags: 22.04, 64-bit, error-handling, fingerprint-reader

```
fprintd-enroll
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
failed to claim device: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.Internal: Open failed with error: transfer timed out

fprintd-verify
Using device /net/reactivated/Fprint/Device/0
failed to claim device: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.Internal: Open failed with error: transfer timed out
```

```
dpkg -l | grep fprintd
ii  fprintd                                    1.94.2-1ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        D-Bus daemon for fingerprint reader access
ii  libpam-fprintd:amd64                       1.94.2-1ubuntu0.22.04.1                  amd64        PAM module for fingerprint authentication through fprintd
```

The windowing system is Wayland

Comment: Attach `lsusb` terminal command output